# find text sequences and create new files with replacement text

Tags: perl, replace

I'm trying to find a way to write a script that does the following:

- Open and detect the first use of a three-letter sequence that is repeated in the input file
- Edit and permute this three letter sequence 19 times, giving 19 outputs each with a different three letter code that corresponds to a list of 19 possible three letter codes

Essentially, this is a fairly straightforward find and replace problem that I know how to do. The problem is that I then need to loop this so that, after creating the 19 files from the previous line, the next line with a *different* three letter code has the same replacement done to it.

I'm struggling to find a way to have the script recognize sequences of text when it can be one of twenty different things.

Let me know if anyone has any ideas on how I could go about doing this, I'll provide any clarification if necessary too!

Here is an example of an input file:

```
ATOM      1  N   SER A   2      37.396  -5.247  -4.830  1.00 65.06           N  
ATOM      2  CA  SER A   2      37.881  -6.354  -3.929  1.00 64.88           C  
ATOM      3  C   SER A   2      36.918  -7.555  -3.786  1.00 64.14           C  
ATOM      4  O   SER A   2      37.287  -8.576  -3.177  1.00 64.31           O  
ATOM      5  CB  SER A   2      38.251  -5.804  -2.552  1.00 65.31           C  
ATOM      6  OG  SER A   2      37.122  -5.210  -1.918  1.00 66.94           O  
ATOM      7  N   GLU A   3      35.705  -7.438  -4.342  1.00 62.82           N  
ATOM      8  CA  GLU A   3      34.716  -8.539  -4.306  1.00 61.94           C  
ATOM      9  C   GLU A   3      35.126  -9.833  -5.033  1.00 59.71           C  
ATOM     10  O   GLU A   3      34.927 -10.911  -4.473  1.00 59.23           O  
ATOM     11  CB  GLU A   3      33.328  -8.094  -4.789  1.00 62.49           C  
ATOM     12  CG  GLU A   3      32.291  -7.994  -3.693  1.00 66.67           C  
ATOM     13  CD  GLU A   3      31.552  -9.302  -3.426  1.00 71.93           C  
ATOM     14  OE1 GLU A   3      32.177 -10.254  -2.892  1.00 73.96           O  
ATOM     15  OE2 GLU A   3      30.329  -9.364  -3.723  1.00 74.25           O  
ATOM     16  N   PRO A   4      35.663  -9.732  -6.280  1.00 57.83           N  
ATOM     17  CA  PRO A   4      36.131 -10.951  -6.967  1.00 56.64           C
```

Where an output would look like this:

```
ATOM      1  N   ALA A   2      37.396  -5.247  -4.830  1.00 65.06           N  
ATOM      2  CA  SER A   2      37.881  -6.354  -3.929  1.00 64.88           C  
ATOM      3  C   SER A   2      36.918  -7.555  -3.786  1.00 64.14           C  
ATOM      4  O   SER A   2      37.287  -8.576  -3.177  1.00 64.31           O  
ATOM      5  CB  SER A   2      38.251  -5.804  -2.552  1.00 65.31           C  
ATOM      6  OG  SER A   2      37.122  -5.210  -1.918  1.00 66.94           O  
ATOM      7  N   GLU A   3      35.705  -7.438  -4.342  1.00 62.82           N  
ATOM      8  CA  GLU A   3      34.716  -8.539  -4.306  1.00 61.94           C  
ATOM      9  C   GLU A   3      35.126  -9.833  -5.033  1.00 59.71           C  
ATOM     10  O   GLU A   3      34.927 -10.911  -4.473  1.00 59.23           O  
ATOM     11  CB  GLU A   3      33.328  -8.094  -4.789  1.00 62.49           C          
ATOM     12  CG  GLU A   3      32.291  -7.994  -3.693  1.00 66.67           C  
ATOM     13  CD  GLU A   3      31.552  -9.302  -3.426  1.00 71.93           C  
ATOM     14  OE1 GLU A   3      32.177 -10.254  -2.892  1.00 73.96           O  
ATOM     15  OE2 GLU A   3      30.329  -9.364  -3.723  1.00 74.25           O  
ATOM     16  N   PRO A   4      35.663  -9.732  -6.280  1.00 57.83           N  
ATOM     17  CA  PRO A   4      36.131 -10.951  -6.967  1.00 56.64           C
```

On the first pass, the `SER` should be changed to a series of twenty different text sequences, the first being `ALA`. The issue I'm having is that I'm not sure how to write a script that will change more than one line of text.

My current script can form the 19 mutations of the first `SER`, but that's where it will stop. It won't mutate the next one, and it won't mutate a different three letter code, for example it wouldn't change the GLU. Is there any easy way to integrate this functionality?

Currently, the way I've approached this is to do a simple text transformation using sed, but as this seems more complicated than what sed can bring to the table, I think perl is likely the way to go. I can add the sed code, but I didn't think it would be of much help.

Comment: Hi George, it's hard to understand exactly what you mean without a concrete example. Please edit your question to include some sample input and the corresponding output you'd like to generate. It would also help if you included a snippet of the code you're using so we can see exactly what part you're having trouble with.

Comment: and please format your text

Comment: I've added a concrete example of the intended input and output, hopefully that'll make  what I'm trying to say a little easier to understand.

Comment: I'm not a biochemist, but those look like PDB files. You might consider looking at some existing modules for parsing PDB files, like [ParsePDB](http://comp.chem.nottingham.ac.uk/parsepdb/), [Bio::PDB::Structure::Atom](https://metacpan.org/pod/Bio::PDB::Structure::Atom), and [Chemistry::File::PDB](https://metacpan.org/pod/Chemistry::File::PDB) (there are probably others, those are just the ones I found in a quick search). These *might* have built-in functionality to help you solve your problem more easily than if you were to write your own parsing logic.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I don't understand how `ALA` can be a permutation of `SER`. Are you saying that you want each line replaced with nineteen new lines that contain all nineeteen different possibilities for column 4 and the other columns remain the same?

Comment: Edit and add what you already have - would be easier guessing what you really want. From where you get the `ALA` in the result?

Comment: Borodin, yeah, you're right on a number of fronts. This is a modified PDB file. I don't think the existing modules will have this functionality, as what I'm doing isn't what's traditionally done in literature. 

You are right, I am intending to replace simply column 4, 19 times. This would produce 19 mutated files each with a different 3 letter code in each line. The difficulty is then adding the functionality to have the script go to the next line and replace, for example, the next few SER's and the GLU and PRO codes.

Comment: @jm666 the ALA in the result is one of 20 different three letter codes contained in a text file.

Comment: @George i don't see the the `ALA` string nowhere in your input file. You mean some other input file(s)?

Comment: Yes, the input file is the file that needs to be modified, the variables are contained in another file. They are listed one to a line with no additional text.

Comment: So every time you come across a change in amino acids, you want to create a new set of 19 other files where the current AA is replaced? Are you planning to have one file where the changed AAs are all ALA, one where they are all ASP, etc.?

Comment: Not quite, @ialarmedalien. Each time I come across the first iteration of a residue, I want to create 19 files where the AA is changed. Then, for the next residue, I want to do the same thing. That is, create 19 files where the 2nd AA is changed, but the first AA is the same as the original.

Comment: OK. So the process is: find first incidence of residue X. Create 19 files with that residue replaced by the other AAs. Continue until you reach a change in AAs. Create new batch of 19 files with that AA replaced. etc.?

Comment: I think so, find first incidence of residue X. Make 19 mutant files. Next line, with a residue that could be X, or could be one of the other 19 amino acids, make a batch of 19 files with this AA replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question and comments aren't entirely clear, but I believe this script will do what you want. It parses a PDB file until it reaches the amino acid of interest. A set of 19 files are produced where this AA is substituted by the other 19 AAs. From there onwards, every time an AA differs from the AA in the previous line, another set of 19 files will be generated.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

# we're going to start mutating when we find this residue.
my $target = 'GLU';

my @aas = ( 'ALA', 'ARG', 'ASN', 'ASP', 'CYS', 'GLU', 'GLN', 'GLY', 'HIS', 'ILE', 'LEU', 'LYS', 'MET', 'PHE', 'PRO', 'SER', 'THR', 'TRP', 'TYR', 'VAL' );

my $prev = '';
my $line_no = 0;
my @lines;
my %changes;

# uncomment the following lines and comment out "while (<DATA>) {"
# to read the input from a file

# my $input = 'path/to/pdb_file';
# open( my $fh, "<", $input ) or die "Could not open $input: $!";
# while (<$fh>) {
while (<DATA>) {
    # split the line into columns (assuming it is tab-delimited;
    # switch this for "\s+" if it is separated with whitespace.
    my @cols = split "\t";

    if ($target && $cols[3] eq $target) {
        # Found our target residue! unset $target so that the following
        # set of tests are performed
        undef $target;
    }

    # see if this AA is the same as the AA in the previous line
    if (! $target && $prev ne $cols[3]) {
        # if it isn't, store the line number and the amino acid
        $changes{ $line_no } = $cols[3];
        # update $prev to reflect the new AA
        $prev = $cols[3];
    }
    # store all the lines
    push @lines, $_;
    # increment the line number
    $line_no++;
}

# now, for each of the changes, create substitute files
for (keys %changes) {
    create_substitutes($_, $changes{$_}, [@aas], [@lines]);
}

sub create_substitutes {
    # arguments: line no, $res: residue, $aas: array of amino acids,
    # $all_lines: all lines in the file
    my ($line_no, $res, $aas, $all_lines) = @_;

    # this is the target line that we want to substitute
    my @target = split "\t", $all_lines->[$line_no];

    # for each AA in the list of AAs, create a new file called 'XXX-##.txt',
    # where XXX is the amino acid and ## is the line number where the
    # substituted residue is.
    for (@$aas) {
        next if $_ eq $res;
        open( my $fh, ">", $_."-$line_no.txt") or die "Could not create output file for $_: $!";
        # print out all lines up to the changed line
        print { $fh } @$all_lines[0..$line_no-1];
        # print out the changed line, substituting in the AA
        print { $fh } join "\t", @target[0..2], $_, @target[4..$#target];
        # print out the rest of the lines.
        print { $fh } @$all_lines[$line_no+1 .. $#{$all_lines}];
    }
}


__DATA__
ATOM    1   N   SER A   2   37.396  -5.247  -4.830  1.00    65.06   N
ATOM    2   CA  SER A   2   37.881  -6.354  -3.929  1.00    64.88   C
ATOM    3   C   SER A   2   36.918  -7.555  -3.786  1.00    64.14   C
ATOM    4   O   SER A   2   37.287  -8.576  -3.177  1.00    64.31   O
ATOM    5   CB  SER A   2   38.251  -5.804  -2.552  1.00    65.31   C
ATOM    6   OG  SER A   2   37.122  -5.210  -1.918  1.00    66.94   O
ATOM    7   N   GLU A   3   35.705  -7.438  -4.342  1.00    62.82   N
ATOM    8   CA  GLU A   3   34.716  -8.539  -4.306  1.00    61.94   C
ATOM    9   C   GLU A   3   35.126  -9.833  -5.033  1.00    59.71   C
ATOM    10  O   GLU A   3   34.927  -10.911 -4.473  1.00    59.23   O
ATOM    11  CB  GLU A   3   33.328  -8.094  -4.789  1.00    62.49   C
ATOM    12  CG  GLU A   3   32.291  -7.994  -3.693  1.00    66.67   C
ATOM    13  CD  GLU A   3   31.552  -9.302  -3.426  1.00    71.93   C
ATOM    14  OE1 GLU A   3   32.177  -10.254 -2.892  1.00    73.96   O
ATOM    15  OE2 GLU A   3   30.329  -9.364  -3.723  1.00    74.25   O
ATOM    16  N   PRO A   4   35.663  -9.732  -6.280  1.00    57.83   N
ATOM    17  CA  PRO A   4   36.131  -10.951 -6.967  1.00    56.64   C
ATOM    18  CA  ARG A   4   36.131  -10.951 -6.967  1.00    56.64   C
```

This example data will produce a set of files for the first GLU found (line 6), then another set for line 15 (PRO residue), and another set for line 17 (ARG residue).

Example of ALA-6.txt file:

```
ATOM    1   N   SER A   2   37.396  -5.247  -4.830  1.00    65.06   N
ATOM    2   CA  SER A   2   37.881  -6.354  -3.929  1.00    64.88   C
ATOM    3   C   SER A   2   36.918  -7.555  -3.786  1.00    64.14   C
ATOM    4   O   SER A   2   37.287  -8.576  -3.177  1.00    64.31   O
ATOM    5   CB  SER A   2   38.251  -5.804  -2.552  1.00    65.31   C
ATOM    6   OG  SER A   2   37.122  -5.210  -1.918  1.00    66.94   O
ATOM    7   N   ALA A   3   35.705  -7.438  -4.342  1.00    62.82   N
ATOM    8   CA  GLU A   3   34.716  -8.539  -4.306  1.00    61.94   C
ATOM    9   C   GLU A   3   35.126  -9.833  -5.033  1.00    59.71   C
```

(etc.)

If this isn't the correct behaviour, you'll have to edit your question as it isn't very clear!

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it. I truly apologize for being unclear, I was struggling to describe the behavior. This is amazingly helpful and is far more than I had expected. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Because your question isn't very clear (more precisely, it is totally unclear), i created the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.014;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Path::Tiny;
use Bio::PDB::Structure;
use Data::Dumper;

my $residues_file = "input2.txt";   #residue names, one per line
my $molfile = "m1.pdb";             #molecule file

#read the residues
my(@residues) = path($residues_file)->lines({chomp => 1});

my $m= Bio::PDB::Structure::Molecule->new;

for my $res (@residues) {       #for each residue name from a file "input2.txt"
    $m->read("m1.pdb");         #read the molecule
    my $atom = $m->atom(0);     #get the 1st atom
    $atom->residue_name($res);  #change the residue to the from file

    #create output filename
    my $outfile = path($molfile)->basename('.pdb') . '_' . lc($res) . '.pdb';
    #write the result
    $m->print($outfile);
}
```

for example, if the `input2.txt` contains

```
ALA
ARG
ASN
ASP
CYS
GLN
GLU
GLY
HIS
ILE
LEU
LYS
MET
PHE
PRO
SER
THR
TRP
TYR
VAL
```

the from your input, generates 20 files where the residue in the 1st atom is changed (according to your output example) to like:

```
==> m1_ala.pdb <==
ATOM      1  N   ALA A   2      37.396  -5.247  -4.830  1.00 65.06

==> m1_arg.pdb <==
ATOM      1  N   ARG A   2      37.396  -5.247  -4.830  1.00 65.06

==> m1_asn.pdb <==
ATOM      1  N   ASN A   2      37.396  -5.247  -4.830  1.00 65.06

==> m1_asp.pdb <==
ATOM      1  N   ASP A   2      37.396  -5.247  -4.830  1.00 65.06

==> m1_cys.pdb <==
ATOM      1  N   CYS A   2      37.396  -5.247  -4.830  1.00 65.06
```

... etc, 20 times...